# Account for request parameters in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have written a project using Spring Cloud Gateway and I am able to query simple endpoints that take no parameters and return, just a string. I want to expand that to be able to account for request that carry parameters in them such as `@PathParam` or `@RequestParam`, but I cant find a straightforward answer as to how to do it.

Now I have:

```
    @Configuration
    public class SpringCloudConfig {



        @Bean
        public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {  
            return builder.routes()
                    .route(r -> r.path("/employee/**")
                            .uri("http://localhost:8081/")
                            .id("employeeModule"))

                    .route(r -> r.path("/consumer/**")
                            .uri("http://localhost:8082/")
                            .id("consumerModule"))
                    .build();
           }
       }
    }
```

I know that the above works with endpoints that use `@PathVariable` but what if my endpoint was

```
fun balances(@RequestBody balancesRequestData: BalancesRequestData,
             @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)  authHeader : String): ResponseEntity<String> {
```

How would I account for the `@RequestBody` and for the authentication header?

Comment: Why you need to have a roiute config for each individual API? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Your current path predicate accounts for path parameters. You haven't described enough what you are trying to accomplish and what your current configuration doesn't do.

Comment: I want to account for an endpoint that takes a @PathParam, http://localhost:/8082/employee/{salary}, and for an endpoint that takes a RequestParam